# Nested riddles with vegetarian bear

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme

> > Some eating utensils of wood in a pair,
> > ceramic and often expensive dishware,
> > a cute black and white vegetarian bear.
>
> What am I?
>
> > With office or novel; may lead to amen,
> > expressing ideas with one's lips or a pen,
> > the World Cup's been won most by this country's men.
>
> What am I?
>
> > An actor's name backwards or seven times three,
> > the 9d's and 20d's in D&D,
> > with strip or face; game sometimes shown on TV.
>
> What am I?

What am I?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1) Some eating utensils of wood in a pair, ceramic and often expensive dishware, a cute black and white vegetarian bear.  Solved by [QuantumTwinkie](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/73550/19547)

> chopsticks, china and panda: **Chinese**

2 a) With office or novel; may lead to amen,

> an office romance or romance novel; (not sure of amen - perhaps in a wedding) → *romance*

2 b) expressing ideas with one's lips or a pen, the next two parts solved by [Joseph S.](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/73555/19547)

> *language*

2 c) the World Cup's been won most by this country's men.

> *Brazil*

These can give for No. 2

> Romance language spoken in Brazil: **Portuguese**

3) An actor's name backwards or seven times three, the 9d's and 20d's in D&D, with strip or face; game sometimes shown on TV. Solved by [Chowzen](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/73551/19547)

> blackjack, dice/craps and poker: **gambling**

Final answer may be:

> **Macau** - the Chinese and former Portuguese region which is the gambling capital of the world.

Comment: Wow, just now (3 hours later) noticed that you came up with the same conclusion I did, but a few minutes earlier than I. Plus, you did it romantically. :) +1

Answer (score 6):

For number 1 are you

> Chinese cultural things

Some eating utensils of wood in a pair,

> Chopsticks.

ceramic and often expensive dishware,

> Fine China.

a cute black and white vegetarian bear.

> Pandas are Chinese.

Answer (score 5):

Still not sure, but this is where I am.

[As QuantumTwinkie shows](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/73549/nested-riddles-with-vegetarian-bear/73550#73550), #1 points to

> Chinese things (chopsticks, China serving ware, Pandas).

As [Joseph S. indicates](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/73549/nested-riddles-with-vegetarian-bear/73555#73555), #2 might have to do with

> The Language of Brazil, known as Portuguese.

For #3,

> Gambling

An actor's name backwards or seven times three,

> Jack Black/Blackjack

the 9d's and 20d's in D&D,

> Dice/Craps

with strip or face; game sometimes shown on TV.

> Strip Poker, [PokerFace](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bESGLojNYSo), World Series of Poker

This, all put together may indicate

> Macau, China 
>  It is the [gambling capital of the world](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macau) and Macau's official languages are Chinese (Cantonese) and Portuguese.

Answer (score 4):

For #2 are you

> A pregador? (Brazillian preacher)

With office or novel; may lead to amen,

> Pastor or theologian ("amen" is a common statement during sermons)

expressing ideas with one's lips or a pen,

> language

the World Cup's been won most by this country's men.

> Brazil (Brazil has won the most world cups)

Expanded explanation

> The language of Brazil is Portuguese, the Portuguese word for a preacher is "pregador." (I have no idea how this fits in with Chinese culture and gambling though so this is probably all wrong)

Comment: +1 and welcome to Puzzling.SE!  Why not take the [tour](/tour) for an easy badge?